# Can I find the port number if I only have the SOCKET?

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock

Can I find the port number if I only have the SOCKET?  I am hooking ws2_32 calls, and it seems like a SOCKET is trying to send data, but I have no information about this SOCKET.  I want to know if there is anyway to get the sockaddr, or port from just the SOCKET?

I ran into a similar problem with a UDP socket but I fixed it by just getting the port number from the sockaddr when it was about to send data and updated my information about it.  But the problem is, I don't have anything to go off of besides the SOCKET.

The program is making a SOCKET with port 0, and later on it assigns it to a new port.  By the time that happens my program's information on the socket is already set using port 0, which is not true.  So, I need to find a way to either... A: Find the port based on the SOCKET, or B: When windows updates the port, I can hook that and update the port.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two functions that do exactly what you want:

1. `getpeername` - gets the information about the other end of the TCP connection
2. `getsockname` - gets the information about the socket (local end) for both TCP and UDP

Comment: @sirgeorge do you have a sample? I am not able to use getpeername() in a sockets connected with WSAConnectByName. It returns me winsock error  WSAENOTCONN (socket is not connect) when in fact it is connected.

Comment: @Kiewic: What protocol are you using ? If it is UDP, then you cannot use `getpeername`.